# Why I can't re-fetch my website's data using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a practice project which is a clone of the New York Times website. There, I do a default query and fetch some data. But now I want to add the functionality for a user to put their own search-term and fetch new data.

I have an array in which I store all of the data that I fetch from NYT's API and every time I try to use the input field to manually search for data I get this error logged to the console:

[image: the error which is logged to the console]

--

**Here's my JS:**

```
const searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form');
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search-box');
const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results');

const authKey = '*********************';
const apiKey = `api-key=${authKey}`;
const url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json';

let content = [];

// DEFAULT QUERY
async function doQuery(queryTerm) {
  let query = `q=${queryTerm}`;

  const response = await fetch(`${url}?${query}&${apiKey}`);
  const data = await response.json();

  let newContent = data.response.docs.map(doc => ({
    id: doc._id,
    image: `https://www.nytimes.com/${doc.multimedia[5].url}`,
    headline: doc.headline.main,
    abstract: doc.abstract,
    author: doc.byline.original,
    section: doc.section_name,
    words: doc.word_count + ' words',
    readTime: Math.ceil(doc.word_count / 200) + ' min read time',
    rawDate: new Date(doc.pub_date),
    date: new Date(doc.pub_date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    }),
    url: doc.web_url
  }));

  content = [...newContent];
  let li = [];

  for (i = 0, length = content.length; i < length; i++) {
    const pSuper = document.createElement('p');
    pSuper.innerHTML = content[i].section;
    const h3Headline = document.createElement('h3');
    h3Headline.innerHTML = content[i].headline;
    const pAbstract = document.createElement('p');
    pAbstract.innerHTML = content[i].abstract;
    const pSub = document.createElement('p');
    pSub.innerHTML = `${content[i].author} | ${content[i].words} | ${content[i].readTime}`;

    const imgImage = document.createElement('img');
    imgImage.src = content[i].image;

    const divDate = document.createElement('div');
    divDate.innerHTML = content[i].date;
    const divContent = document.createElement('div');
    divContent.append(pSuper, h3Headline, pAbstract, pSub);
    const divCard = document.createElement('div');
    divCard.append(divDate, divContent, imgImage);

    const aLink = document.createElement('a');
    aLink.href = content[i].url;
    aLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    aLink.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener noreferrer');
    aLink.className = 'no-select';
    aLink.append(divCard);

    li = [...li, document.createElement('li')];
    li[i].append(aLink);

    searchResults.append(li[i]);

    // CLASSES
    divCard.className = 'card';
    divDate.className = 'date';
    divContent.className = 'content';

    pSuper.className = 'super';
    h3Headline.className = 'headline';
    pAbstract.className = 'abstract';
    pSub.className = 'sub';
  }
}

doQuery('covid');

// USER QUERY
function doSearch(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  doQuery(searchBox.value);
}

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', doSearch);
```

--

**P.S.**

- You can view the website here: https://sepsol.github.io/covid-news
- You can view the full source code here: https://github.com/sepsol/covid-news

Comment: The `docs` array inside the `response` object contains some object with an empty `multimedia` array. So you are trying to access the index of an empty array i.e `${doc.multimedia[5].url}` it gives you an undefined error.

Comment: I have updated my question with a copy of Postman's response, as you can see the `multimedia` array is not empty at all -- otherwise it wouldn't be able to render the images in the `// DEFAULT QUERY` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all the object that is supposed to contains the image (according to your code) does not exists :

```
...
image: `https://www.nytimes.com/${doc.multimedia[5].url}`,
...
```

A simple way to avoid this may be to use a ternary condition (supposing the API ALWAYS provides the same well formatted object where the image URL is referred by the `multimedia[5].url` property.

For example :

```
...
image: doc.multimedia[5].url === undefined ? /** put some fallback image url HERE */ : `https://www.nytimes.com/${doc.multimedia[5].url}`,
...
```